# Sick lms 200 interface

Tags: ros, laser, sicklms, sick

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello!

I am very new to robotics society, so I apologize for this silly question. I have a sick lms 200 (laser rangefinder) which is not connected to robot yet. I have just connected it to computer and I am able to get data from it by use of drivers produced by sick company. But, I need to interface with it through c++ or MATLAB. Also my system is windows and not LINUX. I do not have that much knowledge of computer science. The ROS developed code is for linux and The ARIA developed codes for interfacing with sick, seems to be written for a robot mounted sick. Therefore, I am not able to use them, because there is no robot installed yet. I will truly appreciate if anyone could help me on this problem. I am confused and I do not know what to do.

Your friend, Ali

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/50320/sick-lms-200-interface/) by [alimohandes](https://answers.ros.org/users/3776/alimohandes/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-12-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You do not need to have a mobile or other robot to use the ROS interface to SICK lasers.   See http://wiki.ros.org/sicktoolbox_wrapper/Tutorials/UsingTheSicklms for a tutorial on setting up the ROS interface for the laser.

Running ROS on a supported version of Ubuntu Linux is easiest, since most of the ROS documentation, packages, etc. are all for Linux.  See  http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Installation and click on the Ubuntu link.  On that page note what versions of Ubuntu it says are supported by the current ROS release.

---

Originally posted by [ReedHedges](https://answers.ros.org/users/422/reedhedges/) with karma: 821 on 2015-06-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0